# Why it is not redirecting to webview?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I click on button, then it should redirect to the default browser in our mobile along with the string entered, that should be passed to the browser. I am using the code below in the controller

```
vm.socialMedialinkOpen = function(url) {
    if (url.indexOf('http://') === 0 || url.indexOf('https://') === 0) {
        $window.open("http://" + url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    } else {
        $window.open(url,'_system','location=yes');
    }
};
```

Please help me I am new to the angular js, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using adding the following code to your `config.xml` file. It causes all external links to be opened in native apps:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

Comment: i saw in config .xml above mentioned links is there in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use [inAppBrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin

Comment: i am working with inAppBrowser also that is also not workout

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if condition is incorrect:

```
if (url.indexOf('http://') === 0 || url.indexOf('https://') === 0) {
```

This will return `true` if `url` starts with with `http://` or `https://`, but you also append `"http://" + url` for true condition.

I guess you just need to swap condition blocks:

```
if (url.indexOf('http://') === 0 || url.indexOf('https://') === 0) {
    $window.open(url,'_system', 'location=yes');
} else {
    $window.open("http://" + url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

Comment: Actually if user enter string data  any thing then redirect to web view with search related links in web view